# How to get count of each fan's likes, comments for posts on Facebook page using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to create app for get users' interaction with page. Each users like, comments, share specific page post.

I want to get count of total likes, comments and shares done by each user.

I used Graph API to return page

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed?fields=id,likes,comments{from},shares
```

i got results similar to this.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "478412518924513_633895136709583", 
      "likes": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "3696534343199936", 
            "name": "User Name"
          }, 
          {
            "id": "576343349495810279", 
            "name": "User name"
          }
        ], 

      }, 

      "comments": {
        "data": [
          {
            "from": {
              "id": "154e3485900543", 
              "name": "user name"
            }, 
            "id": "633895096709587_633907896708307"
          }, 
          {
            "from": {
              "id": "10202701931494709", 
              "name": "User anme"
            }, 
            "id": "633895096709587_633899590042471"
          }
        ], 
      }
    },
```

How can i get how many likes,comments made by each user?

Comment: You mean the total comments, likes etc. every single user ever made  on a Page's feed?

Comment: @Tobi Yes, thats what i need to know. FQL has been deprecated too in v2.1

Comment: I think there is no way. You might have to workaround to get the total likes/comments done by a user.

Answer (score 2):

There are no endpoints you can get these counts from. This means that you have to aggregate the data yourself, namely

1) Iterating over the Page's Feed:

```
GET /{Page_ID}/feed?fields=id,created_time,likes{id},comments{from{id}},sharedposts&limit=200
```

and use the paging info to get the next results

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/feed/#read
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/post#edges

2) Aggregate the resulting data yourself in your application